# How to do a dregradê on wx.Panel Background?

Tags: python, colors, wxpython, panel

I want to color the background (SetBackgroundColour) of a wx.Panel with a blue to black degradê.

How can I make it?

Comment: Curiosity: in which language is it called “degradê”? (I know that in French it's called “degradé”.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapted from [DaniWeb](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread128350-6.html#):

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=(350, 450))
        # this sets up the painting canvas
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        # set frame size to fit panel
        self.Fit()

    def on_paint(self, event):
        # establish the painting canvas
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)
        x = 0
        y = 0
        w, h = self.GetSize()
        dc.GradientFillLinear((x, y, w, h), 'blue', 'black')


app = wx.App(0)
MyFrame(title='Gradient Test').Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

And an alternative way to generate a gradient bitmap, using NumPy (from [wxpython.org](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithImages)):

```
import numpy as np

def GetBitmap( self, width=640, height=480, leftColour=(255,128,0), rightColour=(64,0,255) ):
        ## Create a horizontal gradient
        array = np.zeros( (height, width, 3),'uint8')
        # alpha is a one dimensional array with a linear gradient from 0.0 to 1.0
        alpha = np.linspace( 0., 1., width )
        # This uses alpha to linearly interpolate between leftColour and rightColour
        colourGradient = np.outer(alpha, leftColour) + np.outer((1.-alpha), rightColour)
        # NumPy's broadcasting rules will assign colourGradient to every row of the destination array
        array[:,:,:] = colourGradient
        image = wx.EmptyImage(width,height)
        image.SetData( array.tostring())
        return image.ConvertToBitmap()# wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
```

Comment: thanks m8, you were very fast!

Do you know the answer for this other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375613/is-it-possible-to-dock-wx-auimanager-panes-onto-tops-bottoms-of-another-panes